# Getting AttributeError: 'Picture' object has no attribute 'getFrameColour' while trying to access the array file

Tags: python

The program stores pictures as objects. It stores the dimension, frame colour, and description of the picture. The program needs to input its requirements for a picture. The user will enter colour, width, and height. Then the program will search the array and output the picture description if any picture meets the requirements.

```py
class Picture:

    def __init__(self, DescriptionP, WidthP, HeightP, FrameColourP):
        self.__Description = DescriptionP  # string
        self.__Width = WidthP  # integer
        self.__Height = HeightP  # integer
        self.__FrameColour = FrameColourP  # string


def getDescription(self):
    return self.__Description  # Fixed method to return the associated attribute to the user


def getWidth(self):
    return self.__Width


# Key rule: Only use parameters if they are passed, otherwise only use self and attributes.
def getHeight(self):
    return self.__Height


def getFrameColour(self):
    return self.__FrameColour


# In such questions, do not think much just solve normally. Use the parameters(mentionned...
def SetDescription(self, DescriptionP):
    # ...during class definition) and imagine that they have already been given a value by the user.
    self.__Description = DescriptionP


# Do this to show blank array instead of doing the method where you write 'None' multiple times.
PictureArray = []
# This is class with parameters so can happen directly but can't be blank. In case of...
for i in range(100):
    # ...object with parameters, it has to be defined first(tho can be blank there at least).
    PictureArray.append(Picture("", 0, 0, ""))


def ReadData(PictureArray):  # In object case array is not needed as parameter.
    filename = "C:\\Users\\ayush\\Downloads\\Pictures.txt"
    NumberPicturesInArray = 0
    try:
        file = open(filename, "r")
        # For internal work so .lower() used in string case, or bcoz extra variable avoided.
        Description = (file.readline()).strip().lower()
        while (Description != ""):
            # Just prefer mentionning data type for int(and .lower() here for string).
            Width = int((file.readline()).strip())
            Height = int((file.readline()).strip())
            Frame = ((file.readline()).strip()).lower()
            # Extra step to do when without 'object'...
            PictureArray[NumberPicturesInArray] = Picture(
                Description, Width, Height, Frame)
            # ...where '.append' can be thought to be replaced with '[Counter]='.
            Description = ((file.readline()).strip()).lower()
            NumberPicturesInArray = NumberPicturesInArray+1
        PictureArray.append(Picture(DescriptionP=Description,
                            WidthP=Width, HeightP=Height, FrameColourP=Frame))
        file.close()
    except IOError:
        print("Could not find file!")
    return NumberPicturesInArray, PictureArray


    # In the without 'object' case, when a return value is...
# ...there in function then use it to call the function.
NumberPicturesInArray, PictureArray = ReadData(PictureArray)


# .lower allows any case alphabets to be input but be processesed as lower only!
FrameColour = input("Input the Frame colour ").lower()
MaxWidth = int(input("Input the Maximum Width "))
MaxHeight = int(input("Input the Maximum Height "))
print("Matches Frames shown")
for Z in range(0, NumberPicturesInArray):  # This range is crucial.
    if (PictureArray[Z].getFrameColour() == FrameColour):
        if (PictureArray[Z].getWidth() <= MaxWidth):
            if (PictureArray[Z].getHeight() <= MaxHeight):
                print(PictureArray[Z].getDescription(), " ", str(PictureArray[Z].getWidth()), " ", str(
                    PictureArray[Z].getHeight()), " ", PictureArray[Z].getFrameColour())
```

I'm getting the error-

```
 if (PictureArray[Z].getFrameColour() == FrameColour):
AttributeError: 'Picture' object has no attribute 'getFrameColour'
```

I'm trying to call the method to read the array data.

Expected output- Description of the picture

Comment: Please [edit] your code formatting until the code here looks exactly like your real code. Accurate indentation saves lives.

Comment: If your code actually looks like this, then it cannot possibly work. In Python, indentation is part of the syntax, indicating when a block finishes. Check the indentation in your actual, I suspect it's off given the error message you're showing us.

Comment: @CrazyChucky careful editing code where the issue is likely due to broken indentation. If you guessed wrong you'll end up pulling in misguided answers.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні Generally true, but in this case I didn't change any indentation, just the code fences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__init__` method is correctly indented inside the `Picture` class. However, the other "methods" are not indented at all, so they're not actually part of the class; they're simply top-level functions. So when you create an instance of `Picture`, it does not have a `getFrameColour` method.

You want something more like this:

```
class Picture:
    def __init__(self, DescriptionP, WidthP, HeightP, FrameColourP):
        self.__Description = DescriptionP  #string
        self.__Width = WidthP  #integer
        self.__Height = HeightP  #integer
        self.__FrameColour = FrameColourP  #string

    def getDescription(self):
        return self.__Description

    def getWidth(self):
        return self.__Width

    def getHeight(self):
        return self.__Height

    def getFrameColour(self):
        return self.__FrameColour
```

This does still have some issues. Standard practice in Python is to use "snake_case", for instance using `get_frame_colour` instead of `getFrameColour`; more importantly, you don't really need getter methods at all. It would be much cleaner to use the attributes directly. You might also want to try [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to streamline things.